# Python requests.put() corrupts the uploaded image file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use the Python requests package to upload an image file to my Amazon AWS S3 bucket.

The code I have opens the bucket, downloads an image file, resizes the image, saves the image locally, then tries to upload the saved image to the S3 bucket.

It all works fine except that the uploaded jpg file is corrupt in some way in as much as it can no longer be viewed as an image. I have checked that the original file that is being uploaded is not corrupt.

My code is:

```
conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

for key in bucket.list(prefix='media/userphotos'):
    file_name=key.name
    full_path_filename = 'https://' + settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + file_name
    fd_img = urlopen(full_path_filename);
    img = Image.open(fd_img)
    img = resizeimage.resize_width(img, 800)
    new_filename = full_path_filename.replace('userphotos', 'webversion')
    # Save temporarily before uploading to S3 bucket
    img.save('temp.jpg', img.format)
    the_file = {'media': open('temp.jpg', 'rb')}
    r = requests.put(new_filename, files=the_file, auth=S3Auth(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
    fd_img.close()
```

**UPDATE**

I have just noticed that while the jpg file cannot be opened with a web browser or with Preview on my Mac it can be opened successfully with Adobe Photoshop! Clearly the image is in the file but there is something about the jpg file created by `requests.put()` which is doing something to the file that stops it being readable by web browsers. Strange!

Comment: Can the local file `temp.jpg` be displayed in a web browser?  If you `get()` the file you just `put()` does it come back different?

Comment: Yes the local temp.jpg can be displayed in a web browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a very similar issue, but I'm using requests.post to upload image files to a personally managed Apache web server vs. AWS.

Comment: Hi. Any update on this? I'm having this issue as well. My Setup is same as Brendans'. request.post with managed Apache server.

Answer (score 4):

Do this instead:

```
requests.put(url, data=open(filename, 'rb'))
```

I noticed using "files" as documented in requests library prepends a bunch of garbage to the file. You inspect that with `xxd <filename>`