# How to upload video to wordpress using request post?

Tags: python, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api, python-telegram-bot

Tried million of things and only works from Postman and not from Python, any help?

I tried sending the video using `BytesIO` buffer and it said the media isn't supported and tried using open(file) and said the same thing...

This is the code from Python to upload using open(took from Postman):

```
import base64
import requests



url = "https://{site}/wp-json/wp/v2/media" #not showing the site on purpose

username = "" #security concerns...  
password = ""  
data_sauth = username + ":" + password
token = base64.standard_b64encode(data_sauth.encode())


payload = {'title': 'test111'}
files=[
  ('file',('video123.mp4',open('/Users/{user}/Programming/video123.mp4','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; filename="test123.mp4"',
  'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
  "Authorization": "Basic " + token.decode("utf-8"),
#   "Host": "www.{site}", #tried with and without, not working
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Post created successfully:" + response.text)
    data = response.json()
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    print(f"Link to post: {data['link']} \n ")
else:
    print("Failed to create post: ", response.status_code, response.text)
```

The post is uploaded but the media isn't supported
[Image showing that it isn't being supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxaCo.png)

This is how I tried to upload using Bytes IO on another occasion and got the same error:

```
file_info = await context.bot.get_file(postMediaID)
             file_buffer = io.BytesIO()
             await file_info.download_to_memory(file_buffer)
            
             result = wp_connection.postWpMedia(
                 title=postTitle, media_content=file_buffer.getvalue(), status=postStatus
             )
```

Reminding again that Postman did the job good, but I couldn't replicate it on Python.

Comment: No clue why....

Comment: Yepp! I figured that I need to use data instead of files in request.post. look at my answer below! @Sauron

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got a piece of code that says how to solve this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633086/8971211

```
requests.put(url, data=open(filename, 'rb'))
```

> I noticed using "files" as documented in requests library prepends a
> bunch of garbage to the file. You inspect that with xxd